# checked_array_iterator<T> in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, portability

C++11 provides `std::array<T>` to wrap C arrays, but only where you know the array size at compile time.  What is the best way of handling arrays whose size is only known at runtime?

**Background**

I'm porting some code from MSVC to GCC.  MSVC provides the `stdext::checked_array_iterator<T>` template to provide some protection for lines of code such as this:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), stdext::checked_array_iterator<int*>(arr, numVals));
```

So far I can think of two options:  abandoning the safety check or writing my own implementation.  On that note, I'd be grateful for any constructive comments on this implementation:

```
namespace stdext {
    template<typename T>
    struct checked_array_iterator
    {
    private:
        T _val;
        size_t _len;
    public:
        typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type value_type;
        checked_array_iterator(T val, size_t len) : _val(val), _len(len) {}
        checked_array_iterator<T> operator++(int)
        {
            if(_len == 0)
                throw std::range_error("Array iterator overrun");
            checked_array_iterator<T> retval = *this;
            _val++;
            _len--;
            return retval;
        }
        checked_array_iterator<T> & operator++()
        {
            if(_len == 0)
                throw std::range_error("Array iterator overrun");
            _val++;
            _len--;
            return *this;
        }
        value_type & operator*()
        {
            return *_val;
        }
        bool operator==(checked_array_iterator<T>& other) { return other._val == _val; }
        bool operator!=(checked_array_iterator<T>& other) { return !(other == *this); }
        T operator->() { return _val; }
    };
}
namespace std
{
    template <typename T>
    struct iterator_traits<stdext::checked_array_iterator<T>>
    {
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
        typedef typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type value_type;
        typedef T pointer;
        typedef value_type& reference;
        typedef std::input_iterator_tag iterator_category;
    };
}
```

Comment: `What is the best way of handling arrays whose size is only known at runtime?` That would be `std::vector`

Comment: Thanks.  I don't have the option.

Comment: Unless you're suggesting copying the array into a vector just so I can copy it somewhere else.

Comment: Why can't the data start its life in a vector to begin with? Why does it need to touch an array at all?

Comment: If you need MSVCs `stdext::checked_array_iterator<T>`, can't you simply check how it's made there and copy it? It's a template, should be quite easy to find. Or did you already try that out?

Comment: `checked_array_iterator` doesn't offer too much protection. The user is still required to pass the correct size in.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  The array comes from a Fortran module.

Comment: @PawełStawarz in my bit of the world we call that 'copyright violation'.

Comment: @Tom Copying a mere snippet isn't copyright violation. Copying a whole module is however. At least in my bit of the world. AFAIK when you copy a part of the code and change it, its considered derivative work in the US too, and that's legal.

Comment: Creating derivative works is one of the rights protected by copyright, in most jurisdictions.  But, in the end, the answer is that for me to do that, even if it **is** okay, I'd have to get lawyers involved to **say** it's okay.  It's not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this be so bad?

```
if (v.size() > numVals)
  throw std::runtime_error("oops");
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), arr);
```

It's more efficient too, because it checks just once that the size is OK, rather than once per element.

Comment: Yes, that might be the best way.

Comment: Apparently that would be so bad, at least according to Microsoft; this gives a warning 4996, and one that can't be suppressed by `#pragma warning( disable : 4996 )`.

Comment: Looks like MSVC has some brain damage here: http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=259

Comment: Well, a slow clap for Microsoft.

Comment: I've ended up with `namespace stdext { template<typename T> inline T* checked_array_iterator(T* arr, size_t numVals) { return arr; } }` in the Linux build.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, you could use [Eigen Map](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html) (or write a similar implementation). It is essentially a vector which does not manage its own storage but gets pointer and size in its constructor. In that regard, it is quite similar to the level of safety provided by `stdext::checked_array_iterator<T>`. On the other hand, it is not meant to be an iterator, it is meant to be a matrix (or vector as a special case) class. Ane Eigen is both free and multi-platform.